# What exactly does $\left. f(x)+g(x) \right|_{a}^{b}$ mean?

Tags: integration, notation, indefinite-integrals

So we know that

$$\left[ x^2+2x \right]_{a}^{b} = b^2+2b-a^2-2a$$

This is quite clear from the notation. However, there's another fairly common evaluation notation, as follows:

$$\left. x^2+2x \right|_{a}^{b}$$

In this case, it becomes a but confusing. The question then is whether it means $\left[ x^2+2x \right]_{a}^{b}$ or $x^2 + \left[ 2x \right]_{a}^{b}$.

This is quite important when writing things like

$$\left. x^3-4x \right|_{1}^{2} + \left. x^2+2x \right|_{3}^{4}$$

where it's not completely clear if the $3$ and $4$ limits refer to the $x^2+2x$ or just the $2x$. This problem can prop up when integrating by parts or doing some questions.

Which one does it apply to, then? Does the evaluation symbol "$|$" apply to all terms before it, up until the next evaluation symbol on the left?

Comment: Your doubt shows the usefulness of using correctly parentheses... I think that we have to read it as $[f(x)+g(x)]^b_a$.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Do you mean to say that the square brackets on both sides is better or more "correct" than the $|$ symbol on the right? The reason I asked was because I see it fairly often, which I wouldn't have expected to see if it wasn't as correct. Then again, maybe it's just being used a lot when it shouldn't be.

Comment: To me, $|$ is a three-place function (in which one of the places is a function $f$ and the other two are members of the domain of $f$) which mathematicians usually choose to write using suffix notation. I don't think I ever worried about this, but thinking about it, parentheses are indeed necessary (the same way they are necessary when one uses prefix notation, as one usually does).

Comment: If $\left. f(x)+g(x) \right|_{a}^{b}$ is the answer of an integral whose limits are $a$ and $b$, we can usually dispense with the parentheses. But it wouldn't be an error to include them.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that it's okay if it's clear in the context what it is referring to?

Comment: I had a brainfart, I meant [postfix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @SkeletonBow I don't think anyone can deny that it is as much OK as it is to write $\sin t+1$. I don't think this is OK, but many people do.